# Como se que metodos y atributos necesito, si utilizar parametros o argumentos

Tags: java

Mi problema es que no se como plantear el ejercicio, no pido la solución.
Dispongo de un profesor particular, necesito el enfoque para realizar el ejercicio desde una clase y métodos.

A lo mejor debería empezar con algo mas fácil para ir cogiendo ritmo, si me podéis orientar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentando hasta ahora?

Comment: Crear una clase iniciar atributos, iniciarlos desde el método , y desde la clase main usando un equals para controlar la entrada de carácters y que ponga los que yo quiero. También e pensado hacerlo con un switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El enunciado del problema no da muchos detalles, pero puedes empezar preguntándote cuales son las entidades básicas del problema. Para ello busca en el enunciado los sustantivos y demás palabras claves. Por ejemplo en tu enunciado, podría ser Librería, Libro, Venta.

De estas entidades, trata de buscar propiedades que aparezcan en el enunciado. De librería no tenemos muchos datos. De libro sabemos que tiene un tipo de libro que parece un dato de tipo texto. En cuanto a Venta sabemos que se venden Libros (de algún tipo) con una forma de pago que puede ser o "Al contado" o "Con tarjeta". Si no tenemos muchos datos sobre una entidad (Librería) o la entidad es demasiado sencilla (Libro) podemos ignorarlas. Por lo que nos queda Venta con un atributo de tipo texto con el tipo, y otro atributo que podría representarse como una cadena, un tipo enumerado o un valor booleano.  Cada uno tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, yo seguramente lo haría con una cadena.

Con esta entidad ya tendrías una clase con sus dos atributos, para guardar los datos de la aplicación en memoria. Ya que tienes unos atributos privados, podrías tener también sus pares de métodos getter y setter.

Por otra parte, si buscas en el texto las personas que intervienen, te darás cuenta de que hay un actor, el "Operador". Y que el interactúa con el sistema escribiendo texto. Por lo que parece en principio estamos hablando de un programa en modo texto que pedirá una entrada al operador. Por lo que ahí tendrías una clase que sea la encargada de ejecutar este programa y sirva de punto de entrada (clase con método main).

El programa entonces hará varias veces algo (pedir una entrada al operador). Ahí ya te está pidiendo que realices algún tipo de bucle. Cuando tengas que hacer un bucle, lo que te tienes que preguntar es, cuantas veces tengo que iterar, que condición se debe de dar para que pare, y que hacer en cada iteración. En tu caso, se repetiría infinitas veces hasta que el usuario escriba fin.

En cada iteración el sistema le va a pedir al operador el tipo de libro y el método de pago. Por lo que dentro de ese bucle tendrás que pedir dichos datos e irlos guardando en algún tipo de colección que acepte datos de tipo Venta (como por ejemplo un array o una lista), de la que ya tienes la clase hecha.

Una vez el usuario ha escrito "fin", el sistema tiene que generar un informe, que se supone que saldría por pantalla, aunque podría ser a fichero, por red, etc. Suponiendo que lo saque en pantalla, el sistema tendría que preparar cuatro cálculos diferentes: una lista en la que salga la frecuencia de venta de los libros, uno para el porcentaje de ventas al contado, uno para el porcentaje de ventas con tarjeta y el tipo de libro menos vendido.

Para generar el informe podrías ir buscando en tu colección las diferentes ventas (bucle) e ir sumando y acumulando los totales de los métodos de pago para cada tipo de libro e irlos mostrando por pantalla. El total sería el total de cada tipo de libro encontrado y el porcentaje la división del total de ventas de un tipo de libro entre el total de todas las ventas multiplicado por 100. Mientras haces esto, puedes ir calculando el tipo de libro menos vendido. Tomas el primer tipo de libro como el que tiene menos ventas, y si encuentras otro tipo de libro con menos ventas que el mínimo, ese pasaría a ser el nuevo mínimo. Por ejemplo empiezas con Economía con 3 ventas, si te viene luego Informática con 1 venta, Informática pasaría a ser el nuevo mínimo. Si te llega Matemáticas con 2 ventas, no harías nada porque es más que el mínimo actual (1 venta de Informática).

Para calcular el porcentaje de ventas al contado, tendrás que ir uno por uno en cada venta que hayas guardado (otro bucle) e ir sumando las que sean al contado. Si el usuario ha metido 4 ventas y 1 es al contado, tendrás que presentar un 25%. Esto lo calculas dividiendo las ventas al contado encontradas entre el número de ventas introducidas y multiplicando por 100.

Para calcular el porcentaje de ventas con tarjeta, lo puedes hacer o calculándolo de la misma manera pero contando las ventas con tarjeta en vez de las que son al contado. O puedes devolver 100 menos el porcentaje de ventas al contado ya que en principio son excluyentes. Yo seguramente lo haría de la primera manera, por si después aparece un nuevo tipo de pago y esta fórmula no te funciona.

Todos estos cálculos los sacas por pantalla, fichero o lo que sea y acabas el programa cerrando los recursos que fuesen necesarios. Si has abierto un fichero por ejemplo, lo cierras.

Intenta algo de código y si te atascas, pega lo que tengas y lo tratamos de arreglar.

Comment: Tengo un conocimiento limitado, en el centro docente de momento nos han enseñado formar clases con su constructor metodos getter y setter, no nos han enseñado a usar arrays ni colecciónes tampoco nos lo deja usar, y bucles solo while(do while y for no nos deja por qué no se ha enseñado aun).

Comment: Entiendo entonces que de momento solo tendrías que definir la clase de Venta con sus atributos tipoDeLibro y formaDePago. Cuando podáis usar más cosas, con lo que te he puesto tendrías la forma de solucionar el problema al completo.

Comment: Por cierto @MartianCode8, sería genial si cuando hayas avanzado con el temario y ya hagas bucles, listas, etc. pegases el código con todo el ejercicio resuelto. Ánimo y a seguir así :-)